# brightness not working for Dell inspiron 3542

Tags: 16.04, brightness

Brightness is not working,Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron 3542.Also Tried 
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller, still not working

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me 2 times when brightness was not working what I did, I installed nothing and only cleaned it via its recovery mode. After it I directly resumed to Ubuntu and checked everything was working. Moreover, when mouse or touch-pad does not work or error comes while starting Ubuntu I do the same. I have stopped automatic updates and now I update it manually. Apart from this, after every installation of update I clean it from its recovery mode which is in grub's advance options.